# CodeCommit uses origin repo on eb create command instead of another one specified on eb init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, aws-codecommit

`eb create` CLI command throws an error in the middle of the process of its invocation when I answer no here (N):

```
Would you like to enable Spot Fleet requests for this environment? (y/N): 
Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
Could not push code to the CodeCommit repository:
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: fatal: repository 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/origin/' not found
```

I would like to say that when I use `eb init` it prompt me with another name and I don't see origin in the list of reposes on my `CodeCommit` console like it requested here `/v1/repos/origin/`

The initial problem started from another initial error which I don't see anymore probably because I've deleted all reposes:

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - "Error making request to CodeCommit: Could not retrieve 01e68ef1194ec988b10cf3dbfb64aecdce625536 (Service: AWSCodeCommit; Status Code: 400; Error Code: CommitIdDoesNotExistException; Request ID: c2ca6d48-8c3c-4c45-844e-223ee2757922; Proxy: null)"
```

So when I started to resolve that issue `Status code 400` I decided to open **AWS CodeCommit** console and deleted all reposes I've created including `origin`.

So when I tried to re init with command `eb init` it prompted me with these options:

```
Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (Y/n): 

Select a repository
1) codecommit-origin
2) origin
3) [ Create new Repository ]
(default is 1):
```

I selected `1` which created `codecommit-origin` repo.

As I understand and it's just assumption `eb create` while creating all things by default wants to use `origin` which is not presented here (there was codecommit-origin but I deleted it):

[image]

So it started from `Status code 400` error and then `Status code 128`

Actually I wanted to start from scratch I removed all instances, load balancer, eb apps and environments and etc. So probably some setup is still somewhere else.

I also terminated un deployed environments locally and deleted `.elasticbeanstalk` folder in my working copy directory.

So maybe for sure it could be easy way to create `origin` repo again when it will ask me on `eb init` setup, but for now I am just testing with no `CodeCommit`.